# Check Proof: (2,x,y) is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

(2,x,y) is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$

Assume $a\in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and $ab \in (2,x,y)$

Assume $a \notin (2,x,y)$ and $b \notin (2,x,y)$

Then, both $a$ and $b$ has a term which does not have $x$, $y$ or a constant which is a multiple of 2.

Then, $ab$ has a term which does not have either $x$, $y$ or a constant which is a multiple of 2.

Contradiction as $ab \in (2,x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Lemma: $\ fg\in I \color{#c00}\iff 2\mid f_0 g_0\iff 2\mid f_0\ \ {\rm or}\ \ 2\mid g_0\color{#c00}\iff f\in I\ \ {\rm or}\ \ g\in I$

**Lemma** $\ \ f \in I=(2,x,y) \color{#c00}\iff 2\mid f_0 := f(0,0).\ \ $  **Proof:** $ $ Reducing modulo $I$ we have

$\!\!\bmod I\!:\,\ x\equiv0\equiv y\,\Rightarrow\, f(x,y)\equiv f(0,0)=f_0,\,$ so $\,f\in I\!\iff f_0 \in I\iff 2\mid f_0,\, $ since

$f_0 \in I \,\Rightarrow\, f_0 = 2g\! +\! xh\! +\! y k\,\Rightarrow\, f_0 = 2g_0\,$ by eval at $\,x=0=y;\,$ conversely $\, f_0 = 2n\in I$

**Remark** $\ $ If you know quotient rings then the above elementwise proof can be reformulated *structurally* as: $\ \Bbb Z[x,y]/(2,x,y)\cong \Bbb Z_2\,$ is a domain so $\,(2,x,y)\,$ is prime. The ring isomorphism can be proved using the standard isomorphism theorems.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clarify how you get from the observation that

> Then, both $a$ and $b$ has a term which does not have $x$, $y$ or a constant which is a multiple of $2$.

to the conclusion that

> Then, $ab$ has a term which does not have either $x$, $y$ or a constant which is a multiple of $2$.

You could give a more explicit description of what such elements of $\Bbb{Z}[x,y]$ look like.

Comment: Could you tell me what extra steps I could write? I thought it was evident that when we multiply the terms from a and b that does not have either ,  or a constant which is a multiple of 2 then ab has a term with the same specifics. Thanks!

Comment: @Dom That would be a fine explanation. I would say that it is an essential part of the proof, evident as it may be. I was thinking that they are precisely the polynomials with odd constant term.

Comment: In addition to indicating why, when you multiply out  the product $ab$ term by term, you get a term of the desired sort, you should probably also point out that you won't get another such term to cancel the one you found.

Comment: @Dom One needs to be much more precise to obtain a *rigorous* proof. See my answer for one way.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?